# Default template value and implicit type conversion

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, default, implicit

I have the following code (https://godbolt.org/z/GP9PrE):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct universalWrapper{
  universalWrapper(T in): t(in) {}
  T t;
};

struct TypeHolder{
  using MyType = int;
};

template<typename T = typename TypeHolder::MyType>
void myFunc(universalWrapper<T> m)
{}


int main() {
  myFunc(10); 
}
```

And compiling it with C++14 gives the following error (clang in this case):

> error: no matching function for call to 'myFunc'
> myFunc(10);
>
> note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'universalWrapper<type-parameter-0-0>' >against
> 'int'
> void myFunc(universalWrapper<T> m)

Is it possible to somehow make it so it's possible to run  `myFunc(10);`?

I know it's possible to use it as `myFunc({10});` but I would like to avoid using braces here.

Comment: what is the aim to have this `universalWrapper<T>` as argument type and have this `universalWrapper` at all?

Comment: template specialization: https://godbolt.org/z/Gxe3n4

Comment: Yes, you can suppress the type deduction: `void myFunc(std::type_identity_t<universalWrapper<T>> m)`.